# How to add space between buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I have being trying to space out for buttons in a python/tkinter quiz I am making. I realise that selecting specific rows doesn't do a lot as the even hiking up the row values massively doesn't stop them being clumped together.
Everything I looked up on how to do this says use padx/pady which I have and it only seems to change the button size not the space between buttons.

```
option1 = Button(root,text=(question_prompts[0])[1],pady= 20,padx = 20,width = 40,command = lambda: entry(1) )
option2 = Button(root,text=(question_prompts[0])[2],padx = 20,pady = 20,width = 40,command = lambda: entry(2) )
option3 = Button(root,text=(question_prompts[0])[3],width = 40,padx = 20,pady = 20,command = lambda: entry(3) )
option4 = Button(root,text=(question_prompts[0])[4],width = 40,padx = 20,pady = 20,command = lambda: entry(4) )

option1.grid(column = 1,row =1, columnspan = 3 )
option2.grid(column = 1,row =2, columnspan = 3 )
option3.grid(column = 1,row = 3 ,columnspan = 3 )
option4.grid(column = 1,row =4, columnspan = 3 )
```

Is the only way to place each one manually surly not?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Try adding `padx=20` and/or `pady=20` to the `.grid(...)`

Comment: Thank you. It was right under my nose but I was looking out to sea for the mistake